# How can i get a acces to the optional value in html file by thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, crud

Got a problem with a access becouse of optional value

```
@RequestMapping("fruitDetail/{id}")
public String fruitDetail(@PathVariable("id") int batchId, Model model, Principal principal) {
    if(principal != null) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
    }

    Optional<Batch> batch = batchService.findById(batchId);

    model.addAttribute("batch", batch);

    List<Integer> qtyList = Arrays.asList(1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);


    model.addAttribute("qtyList", qtyList);
    model.addAttribute("qty", 1);

    return "fruitDetail";
}
```

and in html file i got something like this

```
<input hidden="hidden" th:field="*{batch.batchId}"/>
```

> Property or field 'batchId' cannot be found on object of type
> 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?

when i dont have optional value something like this: {batch.batchId} is working
how can i get a access to this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `Optional` this way, you can try the following options:

```
model.addAttribute("batch", batch.get());
```

`OR`

```
<input hidden="hidden" th:field="*{batch.get().batchId}"/>
```

Comment: This will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if your optional is empty.

Comment: It is up to him to control this situation, he can get rid of it by checking `batch.ifPresent()` outside, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate how you would do this in Java.

For example, if I have the following optionals in Java:

```java
User bob = new User(1, "Bob", 0, "");
Optional<User> user1 = Optional.of(bob);
Optional<User> user2 = Optional.empty();
```

then I would access them in Java as follows:

```java
if (user1.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("none");
} else {
    System.out.println(user1.get().getUserName());
}
```

So, the equivalent in Thymeleaf would be this, using a [conditional expression](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#conditional-expressions) for compactness:

```
<div th:text="${user1.isEmpty()} ? 'none' : ${user1.get().userName}"></div>
<div th:text="${user2.isEmpty()} ? 'none' : ${user2.get().userName}"></div>
```

This works for each case - an empty optional and a non-empty optional.