# How can I access a property of my object Thymeleaf (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Current output on my website...

This is the personal page of --- Optional[User(id=111, username=Juan Lopez, password=Juanini123, post=Hoy es un gran dia)]

Desired output would be just to show the name, "Juan Lopez"

My HTML (Thymleaf)...

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Personal Profile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="positionlist" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(personalUser)}">

        <span>This is the personal page of --- </span>
        <span th:text="${personalUser}"></span>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller (Spring Boot):

```
package com.littlesocial.sm;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @NonNull
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping("/myProfile")
    public String getPersonalUserProfile(Model model){
        userRepository.save(
                new User(111L,"Juan Lopez", "Juanini123", "Hoy es un gran dia"));

                model.addAttribute("personalUser", userRepository.findById(111L));
                return "personalUserProfile";
    }


}
```

I have tried stuff like personalUser.username - but it does not work.

Comment: `th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(personalUser)}` is probably problem!(?) try/better: `th:unless="${personalUser}`. Definitely problem: calling your controller twice.. (id:111L) ..and hopefully "Juanini123" not real password :))

Comment: @xerx593 that was not the problem, it literally just does not allow me to access a proper inside the Optional class that outputs "Optional[User(id=111, username=Juan Lopez, password=Juanini123, post=Hoy es un gran dia)]" and yes, that is my password for everything! just kidding haha

Comment: now, getting you! [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65643440/592355) (accepted answer: 2 alternatives), now you have to consistently to apply to `${personalUser.get().username}` (or what you want to display)

Comment: @xerx593 YESSSS! IT WORKED... I am abt to cry of happiness. Thank you!!!!! Wanna answer the question so I approve it? Or should I do it? Or should we make it a duplicate?

Comment: I share your happiness! Thank You & very Welcome! :-)

Comment: also: `th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(personalUser)}"` -> `th:if="${personalUser.isPresent()}"`!;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make it:

```
<span th:text="${personalUser.get().username}"></span>
```

---

Or:

```
Optional<User> foundInDb = userRepository.findById(111L);
if (foundInDb.present()) {
  model.addAttribute("personalUserName", // e.g.
     foundInDb.get().getUserName()
  );
}
```

with the according:

```
th:text="personalUserName"
```

With many Thx to: [How can i get a acces to the optional value in html file by thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65643440/592355)